# Angular2 IE adds additional slashes to URL after base path

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, angular, angular2-routing

When accessing http://localhost:3000/main for example, right after the page loads, IE adds extra slashes: http://localhost:3000///main/
so when I refresh the page after it I get an error:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any
>   routes: '/main'

Is there a way to configure this path in IE? Chrome is working well without changes in URL. In addition, Firefox 43 is also weird cause it is adding /\ after refreshing page (http://localhost:3000/\main/)

Comment: Are there specific versions of Internet Explorer in which you encounter this issue?

Comment: or Microsoft Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for this problem was that I used "\" instead of "/" on index.html base tag.

This is the good tag definition: 
`<base href="/"/>`